# How to filter table row in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

The table currently show all the database data for all days. For example, 08/06/2016, 08/07/2016, 08/08/2016, 08/09/2016. How can I change so it only can show certain days? Like users enter pick two dates in jQuery UI datapicker, then the table only show that two days' data?

I use Ajax. I pass text box date's data to action method to filter the dates, but has error:

> The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'activityStartTime2' of non-nullable type 'System.DateTime' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult ShowDateTable(System.DateTime, System.DateTime)' in 'ContosoSite.Controllers.ActivitiesController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter.
>   Parameter name: parameters

```
<div>
    Start Date: <input type="datetime" name="startdate" id="start_datepicker2" />
    End Date: <input type="text" name="enddate" id="end_datepicker2" />
</div>

<div>
    <button id="submit_date2" class="btn btn-warning btn-lg">Submit Date</button>
</div>

<div id="display_table2" hidden="true" >
    <p>
        @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
    </p>
    <table class="table">
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ActivityName)</th>
            <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Latitude)</th>
            ....
        </tr>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <a class="btn btn-info btn-lg" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Map", "Activities")'">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker"></span> Map
                    </a>
                </td>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ActivityName)</td>
                <td data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Latitude)</td>
                ....
            </tr>
        }
    </table>
</div>
```

Script

```
<script>
    $("#submit_date2").click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            url: "/Activities/ShowDateTable",
            data : { activityStartTime2: $("#start_datepicker2").val(),
                activityEndTime2: $("#end_datepicker2").val()

            },
            success: function (response) {
                $("#display_table2").show();
            }
        });

        //$("#show_count_number").show();

        //$("#display-start-date").text($("#start_datepicker").val());
        //$("#display-end-date").text($("#end_datepicker").val());
    })
</script>
```

Controller

```
public ActionResult ShowDateTable(DateTime activityStartTime2, DateTime activityEndTime2)
{
    try
    {
        using (var dbShowDate = new ContosoUniversityDataEntities())
        {

            return View(dbShowDate.Activities.Where(a => a.ActivityTime >= activityStartTime2 & a.ActivityTime <= activityEndTime2).ToList());
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return Content("this not correct");
    }
```

Comment: You need to send the value of the datepicker to the server and regenerate the view based on the filter, either by redirecting to a new page or updating the existing page using ajax.

Comment: Hi Stephen, Yes, I use ajax, please review my code. It will awesome if you can provide some feedback. Thanks a lot

Comment: I show the input text code in my top code

Comment: I have similar case when using `$.ajax` for passing date value from custom date editors to controller throwing same exception with non-nullable DateTime parameters (converting to nullable `DateTime?` just passing null value), which solved by converting input parameters to a date string, declare date parameters as string & calling `DateTime.TryParse` as string to date conversion.

Comment: Do **not** use a string! Where is you element with `submit_date2`? Is it a submit button and do you have `<form>` tags. And why are you chaning all the `id` attributes and names of the parameters in your method?

Comment: @StephenMuecke: Should `$("#start_datepicker2").val().toISOString()` become proper way to pass datetime format directly for non-nullable DateTime parameters without additional conversion? If OP will use that, the controller should adjust ISO 8601 format to desired local time with `AddHours` and/or `AddMinutes`.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto, We need far more info from OP to determine the issue (very little of the code makes any sense anyway - the method returns a view but its just thrown away and the original view is displayed)

Comment: Sorry for forgetting posting the submit button code. I added it

Comment: You need to learn to debug your code. What does `console.log($("#start_datepicker2").val());` return (and ditto for the other datepicker)

Comment: I know how to add break point and debug. The problem here is once I go to ~/Activities/ShowDateTable, it will throw the error, I even cannot click a datepicker.

Comment: Read my last comment!

Comment: Check your date format on start_datepicker2 element using what @StephenMuecke said, is it either return null or invalid date format string? If yes, add `toISOString()` after `val()` method and set breakpoint to ensure date format submitted properly. Afterwards, since returned date from `toISOString()` arranged in UTC format, change to local time using `AddHours`/`AddMinutes` to return same date as start_datepicker2.

Comment: I think not the date format reason. Any more solution?

Answer (score 0):

**if your activitystarttime2 and activityendtime in string and ActivityTime in datetime.
Than**

```
return View(dbShowDate.Activities.Where(a => a.ActivityTime >= DateTime.Parse( activityStartTime2) && a.ActivityTime <= DateTime.Parse (activityEndTime2)).ToList());
```

**if both in datetime than simple add & in your query.**

```
return View(dbShowDate.Activities.Where(a => a.ActivityTime >= activityStartTime2 && a.ActivityTime <= activityEndTime2).ToList());
```

Comment: What does this have to do with the question (which is about the exception being thrown)

Comment: it datetime nullable type than use a=>a.ActivityTime.Value

Comment: Add "Value" not help